# Update specific object in array of objects Postgres jsonb

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I am attempting to update a jsonb column `pagesRead` on table `Books` which contains an array of objects. The structure of it looks similar to this:

```
[{
    "book": "Moby Dick",
    "pagesRead": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
    ]
},
{
    "book": "Book Thief",
    "pagesRead": [
    "1",
    "2"
    ]
}]
```

What I am trying to do is update the pagesRead when a specific page of the book is read or if someone has started a new book, add an extra entry into it.

I am able to retrieve the specific book details, but I am unsure about how to update it.

EDIT: So I had to use the Update query from S-Man to add a book entry, but I used the Insert query from Barbaros Özhan to handle updating the page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some thoughts before:

1. You should never store structured data as it is in one column. This yields problems with updates, indexing (so, searching/performance), filtering, everything. Please normalize everything into proper tables and columns
2. You should never store arrays. Normalize it.
3. Do not use type text to store integer (pages)
4. `"pagesRead"` is a sibling of your filter element (`"book"`). This makes it much more complicated to reference it than referencing it as a child. So think about the book name (or better: an id) as key like `{"my_id_for_book_thief": {"name" : "Book Thief", "pagesRead": [...]}}`. In that case, you could use a path for referencing it. Otherwise, we need to extract the array, have a look into each `book` attribute and reference its sibling

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6c8b12cd8cd6853afddbed4e3b6fd3a2)

Adding a `book` is quite simple (Assuming that you are using type `jsonb` instead of type `json`):

```
SELECT mydata || '{"book": "Lord Of The Rings", "pagesRead": []}'
FROM mytable
```

Update:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = mycolumn || '{"book": "Lord Of The Rings", "pagesRead": []}'
```

---

Adding a `pagesRead` value:

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_agg(                                                         -- 4
        jsonb_build_object(                                            -- 3
            'book', elem -> 'book',
            'pagesRead', CASE WHEN elem ->> 'book' = 'Moby Dick' THEN  -- 2
                             elem -> 'pagesRead' || '"42"'
                         ELSE elem -> 'pagesRead' END
        )
    ) as new_array
FROM mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(mydata) as elem                               -- 1
```

1. Extract the array into one record per element
2. Add a page if element contains correct book
3. Rebuild the object
4. Reaggregate your array.

Update would be:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = s.new_array
FROM (
    -- <query above>
) s
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to add a new page for the second book (`Book Thief`), then using `JSONB_INSERT()` function with the following Update Statement will be enough

```
UPDATE books
   SET pagesRead = JSONB_INSERT(pagesRead,'{1,pagesRead,1}','"3"'::JSONB,true)
```

But, in order to make it a dynamical solution, without knowing the position of the book within the main array, and adding the new page number to the end of the `pagesRead` array of the desired book, determine the position, and the related array's length within the subquery as

```
WITH b AS
(
 SELECT idx-1 AS pos1, 
        JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH( (j ->> 'pagesRead')::JSONB )-1 AS pos2
   FROM books 
  CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(pagesRead) 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
  WHERE j ->> 'book' = 'Book Thief'
)
UPDATE books
   SET pagesRead = 
        JSONB_INSERT(
                     pagesRead,
                     ('{'||pos1||',pagesRead,'||pos2||'}')::TEXT[], 
                    --# pos1 stands for the position within the main array
                    --# pos2 stands for the position within the related pagesRead array
                     '"3"'::JSONB, --# an arbitrary page number
                     true --# the new page value will be inserted after the target path
                     ) 
  FROM b
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=008581e40ab53027117466fbff28435f)</kbd>